# Corda receive attachments from RESTful api

Tags: corda

I am building a project using Corda.

I use RESTful api to invoke flows to create and update a state. But how can I upload a pdf file to node using attachment function in Corda?

Any help is appreiciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the built-in webserver, you need to encode the attachment as `multipart/form-data` and post it to `NODE_WEBSERVER_ADDRESS/upload/attachment`.

See an example here: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/blacklist/src/main/resources/blacklistWeb/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring servers then use below logic :

1. create an api that uses the multipart request and include the below
   code in it.

   msg = proxy.uploadAttachment(new ByteArrayInputStream(getZippedBytes(file))).toString();//msg returns the unique hashid for this attachment.
       //getZippedBytes(file)) returns the byte[]